# Add/Subtract long variable from column reference

Tags: excel, vba

I saw a post here earlier which reminded me of a (very basic) problem I have run into every once in a while. I have no idea what a good title would be, I'm pretty sure mine isn't it.

Anyway, let's say I get a column as an integer (let's say it's 4), save it in a variable and then want to write "Test" in the column which is 4 columns to the left and to the right of E1 (meaning A1 and I1). I can do it in two lines of code, either with `Offset` or `Cells`. But how can I do this in one line?

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim colnumber As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    colnumber = 4

    ws.Range("E1").Offset(0, colnumber).Value = "Test"
    ws.Range("E1").Offset(0, -colnumber).Value = "Test" 'works


    ws.Cells(2, 5 + colnumber).Value = "Test2"
    ws.Cells(2, 5 - colnumber).Value = "Test2" 'works

    ws.Range("A3,I3").Value = "Test3" 'works

    ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 5 - colnumber), ws.Cells(4, 5 + colnumber)).Value = "Test4" 'fills up Range("A4:I4")
End Sub
```

The 'ws.Range("A3,I3").Value' is just there for me to show it is possible to write in two non-contiguous cells the same thing in one line of code. What I struggle with is to do this when using `Cells` or something similar (which I think I have to because I want to add/subtract the variable `colnumber`) and in the last line of code it of course fills up the whole range from `A4` to `I4`, which is not what I want, I just want those two singlecells filled.

Comment: What's the point? Two lines is fine, and very readable. One line gets you a longer, not-so-readable line of code. How is that an improvement?

Comment: "Number of lines of code" is not a valid metric of code quality. Fewer lines does not equate better code. Good code is clear code, and clear code has a limited number of instructions per logical line of code. Cramming as many instructions and member calls as you can into a single line of code only serves to make things harder, if not impossible to debug later. Don't golf up production code.

Comment: @BigBen Well, I didn't know how (un)readable it was gonna be, that's why I was asking. If there had been a good solution, it would've been great to use for similar cases with more than two cells (I have a problem where I have to fill and clear about 20 different, non contiguous cells). So the point was to find out what is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Union, Range use two cells as start and end:

```
Union(ws.Cells(2, 5 + colnumber),ws.Cells(2, 5 - colnumber)).Value = "Test4"
```

If you want to use Range create a string of the addresses concatenated with `,`:

```
ws.Range(ws.Cells(4, 5 - colnumber).Address(0,0) & "," & ws.Cells(4, 5 + colnumber).Address(0,0)).Value = "Test4"
```

But that is a lot of typing.

Comment: Upvoted, duh. Though I strain to see why this is an improvement to splitting these into two lines.

Comment: Haha - would upvote again for the even longer `Range` line added, if I could :-) Just demonstrates that you can keep-it-simple-stupid, or complicate as much as you want.